# Как передать id текущего элемента

Tags: javascript, html

К примеру:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/calkulator3.js"></script>
<link href="css/calculator1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <title>test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="mesto">
 <div id="panel1" class="panel"> </div>
<div class="knopki">
<input class="botom_1" type="button" value="1"  id="a1" onClick="change">
<input class="botom_2" type="button" value="2" id="a2" onclick="change()">
<input class="botom_3" type="button" value="3" id="a3" onclick="change()">
<input class="botom_4" type="button" value="4" id="a4" onclick="change()">
<input class="botom_5" type="button" value="5" id="a5" onclick="change()">
<input class="botom_6" type="button" value="6" id="a6" onclick="change()">
<input class="botom_7" type="button" value="7" id="a7" onclick="change()">
<input class="botom_8" type="button" value="8" id="a8" onclick="change()">
<input class="botom_9" type="button" value="9" id="a9" onclick="change()">
<input class="botom_0" type="button" value="0" id="a0" onclick="change()">

</div>
</div>  
 </body>
</html>
```

Чтобы не создавть десять разных функций можно создать одну, которая будет определять id нажатой кнопки и уже из этого айдишника вытаскивать значение. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 4):

Используйте [делегирование событий](http://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation).

Суть такая - вешаем обработчик события click на элемент, который является родителем ваших кнопок. В этот обработчик передается объект события event. У объекта event есть свойство target, которое является ссылкой на объект кнопки, по которой произошел клик. Простой [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/alvoro/dLg3T/).

Comment: [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/7432Y/) с jQuery.

Comment: А я делал параметр в функции change, да и передавал из каждой кнопки свой номер)

Comment: откуда столько много добрых людей

Comment: вообщем разобрался спасибо ребят

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример кода в песочнице:

```js
function give(val) {
  var obj = document.getElementById('block');
  obj.innerHTML = val;
}
```

```css
button {
  width: 150px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3px;
}
#block {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding : 5px;
}
```

```html
<button id="1" onclick="give(this.id)">Click ME!</button>
<button id="2" onclick="give(this.id)">Click ME!</button>
<button id="3" onclick="give(this.id)">Click ME!</button>
<button id="4" onclick="give(this.id)">Click ME!</button>
<button id="5" onclick="give(this.id)">Click ME!</button>
<div id=block></div>
```